# From the opponent team?

Tags: prepositions, prepositional-phrases

Can we write - "I won the match by 54 runs from the opponent team".

The first half of the sentence is correct, I'm confused about "from the opponent team".

Answer (score 0):

> I won the match by 54 runs.

will do.  Delete 'from the opponent team'.

[Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/run)

> run noun (POINT) B2 [ C ] in cricket and baseball, a single point, scored by running from one place to another:
> England need 105 runs to win the game.

Comment: or use "over the **opposing** team"